# Background image not showing up for UITableView in UISplitViewController's master view

Tags: ios4, background-image, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Xib set up for the Master view in a UISplitViewController. The Xib has a view with two subviews: a subview of a UIImageView (that contains the background image) and a grouped style UITableView. When testing, the image view does not show up as the background of the table view.

The background image shows up correctly using the exact same Xib with the iPhone.

Things I have checked:

- Table view's background color is set to Clear Color
- Opaque checked or unchecked has no effect (on the UIView, UIImageView, or UITableView)
- Setting the Alpha to < 1.0 on the UITableView does start to show the UIImage view behind it
- Tested on 3.2 and 4.2

Any ideas on why the UIImage view is not showing up in the background on the iPad (but is okay for the iPhone)?